# Configuring `alignat` from `amsmath`

Tags: align, amsmath, alignment, alignat

There is various documentation on how to use `\alignat`, however I am really struggling to get my head around it!
My particular issue is with the following.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    x \approx 0:
&\qquad
    x &&\asymp \sqrt{\omega/k},
\quad
    k &&\asymp \lg n
&&\quad\text{and}\quad
    1 - x^\epsilon \asymp 1.
\\
    x \approx 1:
&\qquad
    1 - x &&\asymp (\lg n / k) / \lg(k/\lg n),
\quad
    k &&\gg \lg n
&&\quad\text{and}\quad
    1 - x^\epsilon \asymp \epsilon(1-x).
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

This outputs the following.

[image: Output]

As I'm sure you can imagine, I want the `$x \asymp \sqrt{\omega/k}$` to be anchored at the `\asymp`, but without the big gap to the `x`. Similarly for the `k \asymp \lg n`, without the big gap.
I can't for the life of me manage this though!

---

An ideal answer would not only correct this particular code, but come with insight into how to set this sort of thing up in the future. I mostly just guess when it comes to the `&` or `&&`

Comment: What is `\Quad` (with an uppercase Q)?

Comment: DavidCarlisle: done :) \\ Bernard: it's a macro for `\quad\text{#1}\quad` that I made, but forgot wasn't standard; it's removed now, thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each term should be `left & right`  with an `&` between each such term, so

I have set out the input to show that each term is set as `left & reln-symbol right`
with the terms separated by `&` or `\\` depending on whether a linebreak is needed.

It is simper using `align` as then the additional spacing between each term is automatic so you can drop most of the `\quad` spaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

alignat
\begin{alignat*}{4}
x &\approx 0:\qquad
    &
x &\asymp \sqrt{\omega/k},\quad
    &
k&\asymp \lg n\quad\text{and}\quad
    &
1 - x^\epsilon &\asymp 1.
    \\
x &\approx 1:\qquad
    &
1 - x &\asymp (\lg n / k) / \lg(k/\lg n),\qquad
    &
k&\gg \lg n\quad\text{and}\quad
    &
1 - x^\epsilon &\asymp \epsilon(1-x).
\end{alignat*}

align
\begin{align*}
x &\approx 0:
    &
x &\asymp \sqrt{\omega/k},
    &
k&\asymp \lg n\quad\text{and}
    &
1 - x^\epsilon &\asymp 1.
    \\
x &\approx 1:
    &
1 - x &\asymp (\lg n / k) / \lg(k/\lg n),
    &
k&\gg \lg n\quad\text{and}
    &
1 - x^\epsilon &\asymp \epsilon(1-x).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks! \\ Could you explain further what you mean by your sentence? In particular, you have some `&&`s. Plus, surely as soon as I put two `&`s I have `left & right & ??` -- left again? Does that mean I get `left && left && left & right && right & left`, for example?

Comment: @SamT I had missed some cases so the code didn't match what I said, I just updated to fix a few more.   you should not have any `&&`  in this example as you just have 4 relations on each line, each should be  marked as `left &relation right` with three additional `&` separating the relation on each line

Comment: @SamT if you used `align` rather than `alignat` the spacing between the 4 relations woud be automatic and you wouldn't need the `\qquad` spaces.

Comment: (1) So, for example, the second `&` is just giving the spacing? \\ (2) Oh, really? I thought I needed `alignat` in order to have anchors?

Comment: Could you add an example of how to do it with just `align`? I can't get anything resembling something sensible... :/

Comment: @SamT I have updated the answer to hopefully make it clearer (I'll add an align version)

Comment: @SamT align version added

Comment: I see, thanks. So basically `alignat` just gives me more control over the exact spacing issues. But that `align` automatic spacing looks fine. And thank you for the explanation: I understand it much better now!

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement with `eqparbox`  in order to have `\gg` and `\asymp` vertically aligned. I commented out the commands which were not defined and didn't seem to any effect on the result.

The main use of `alignat` is to have full control on the spacing between alignment columns.  Also, you have to remember that in a multicolumn alignment, each alignment column, but the first, is introduced by an `&`, and inside this column, the alignment point is marked by another `&`. That is why, *n* alignment columns require 2n+1 ampersands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Quad}[1]{\makebox[3em]{#1}}
\newcommand{\rbr}[1]{(#1)}
\def\eps{\varepsilon}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{%
\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle{}#2{}$}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
 x &\approx 0:
& x&\asymp \sqrt{\omega/k},
 & \quad
 k &\eqmathbox{\asymp} \lg n
&\Quad{and}
 1 - x^\epsilon & \asymp 1.
%%\label{2eq:pak:x0}
%\nt % ???
\\
x &\approx 1: \qquad
&
 1 - x &\asymp \rbr{\lg n / k} / \lg\rbr{k/\lg n},
 & \qquad
 k &\eqmathbox{\gg} \lg n
&\Quad{and}
 1 - x^\epsilon & \asymp \eps(1-x).
\label{2eq:pak:x1}
%\nt
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! Are `\asymp` and `\gg` now vertically aligned in terms of their centre (rather than left)?

Comment: The `\eqmathbox`s commands I used put their contents  centred in  box (the widest natural width of the contents), so yes, they have the same vertical axis. You can check it with a very large zoom in your pdf viewer.

Comment: @SamT it's affecting horizontal rather than vertical alignment, forcing \asymp to be as wide as \gg, so the `lg` line up. I'm not convinced it helps as it makes the spacing around k\asymp... larger than other uses of \asyp, but if you like it, it's a possibility:-) Unlike `eqnarray` the ams alignments stress natural spacing around the relation rather than aligning the rhs, hence a single `&=` rather than `&=&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, it's only an æsthetic choice. I felt it could be done, as the two symbols  widths  do not differ much.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!