# How Does This Macro/Command Work? And How to Improve It

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, alignment

In another answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494739/81928) the answerer used the following piece of code. (This was an 'add-on' to their answer; the main part of the question is on a different topic, but still to do with alignment. Hence I am asking a new question, rather than following up on that answer.)

```
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathsbox}[2][M]{%
    \eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle{}#2{}$}}
```

The idea is that this *can* be useful for aligning: it puts commands in a centred box (the widest natural width of its contents).
I have a couple of questions and concerns about its usage, hopefully illustrated in the MWE below. (The first is less serious than the second.)

1. This seems to add some spacing: see the difference between lines `1` and `3` with `k` vs `\log n`.
2. It is the maximum width *over the whole document*, not over that specific display.

I would like to know how to remove these issues. However, I don't really understand how the command works, so am struggling to do so myself...

Here is the MWE. (I have used `minipage` just so that it displays in a 'landscape' mode for the SE picture below.)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathsbox}[2][M]{%
    \eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle{}#2{}$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    a &\vert b
\\
    a &\wr b
\\
    a &\eqmathsbox{\vert} b
\\
    a &\eqmathsbox{\wr} b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    k &\ll \log n
\\
    k &\gtrsim \log n
\\
    k &\eqmathsbox{\ll} \log n
\\
    k &\eqmathsbox{\gtrsim} \log n
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    a &\vert b
\\
    a &\wr b
\\
    a &\eqmathsbox{\vert} b
\\
    a &\eqmathsbox{\wr} b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To see the spacing issues (1.) more clearly, one can use the following snippet (with the same preamble).

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    k &\ll \log n
\\
    k &\eqmathsbox{\ll} \log n
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. I guess it is an optical effect: when measure with my  pdf viewer, the distance between the first  and second lines is exactly the same as between the third and fourth lines (15 pt, precision <0.1 pt). 2. There is an optional tag you can use, which is set by default to `M`. It is up to you to decide which formulæ have to grouped with the same tag,. This enables you to have different widths corresponding to diifferent tags.

Comment: `$\displaystyle{}#2{}$` is wrong. Remove the two `{}` pairs.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity regarding point (1.) -- I have tried to improve this now. I have tried all variations of the pairs `{}` (ie with/without each), but none give the correct spacing when used with `align` in the way shown

Comment: @Bernard ah ok, I did have no idea what that `M` was doing! Is this letter just an arbitrary choice? If I write `\eqmathsbox[a]{...}` or `\eqmathsbox[b]{...}`, these seem to be be 'decorrelated' -- is this the correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, absolutely (see the documentation of `eqparbox` for more details). I chose `M`  for `maths` as the default, to spare  having to type the tag in most cases

Comment: I see, perfect, thank you. That sorts (2.)! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you're using the “equalized boxes” you need a different definition. In particular you have to provide a unique label for the set of boxes to equalize.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathsbox}[3][\mathord]{%
  % #1 = atom type, #2 = label, #3 = object
  #1{\eqmakebox[#2]{$\displaystyle#3$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    a &\vert b
\\
    a &\wr b
\\
    a &\eqmathsbox[\mathbin]{A}{\vert} b
\\
    a &\eqmathsbox[\mathbin]{A}{\wr} b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    k &\ll \log n
\\
    k &\gtrsim \log n
\\
    k &\eqmathsbox[\mathrel]{B}{\ll} \log n
\\
    k &\eqmathsbox[\mathrel]{B}{\gtrsim} \log n
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

1. The `{}` pairs in the original definition are wrong and they're the cause for the excess space in front of the logarithm.
2. The label should be explicitly used, because it is global. With the original definition all `\eqmathsbox` constructions without an optional argument would be equalized *throughout* the document.
3. I added an optional argument for stating the atom type.

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! `:)` I guess maybe the `atom` type is key here, because if I removed the `{}`pairs, as you have done, without this, then the spacing was still wrong. Thanks for your help -- as you have helped many times!

Comment: I still use this answer of yours a great deal, thanks @egreg! I wonder if you could add one small thing to it: a list of what the atom types are. I can guess some, but I have really struggled to find a good list. Most of my searches bring up pages about the `atom` package or editor!

Comment: @SamOT `\mathop`, `\mathord`, `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, `\mathpunct`.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. I can guess what some of those are, but not all... Eg, I guess `\mathbin` is a binary relation---oh, as you have used in your example!---but how is this different to `\mathrel`?

Comment: @SamOT `\mathbin` is for a binary *operation*, with slightly smaller spacing around than `\mathrel` (and different rules for space insertion).

Comment: Thank you. These tid bits are helping, but perhaps you can summarise them, including a link to full details? I was hesitant to include my *example* in the previous comment, in case you merely answered that one. I also don't know what `\mathop` or `\mathord` do. I don't fully understand the others, too. I doubt I am the only one who doesn't know this stuff, but, as I said, I couldn't find good documentation... :/